# Why could a #define be causing problems in a header?

Tags: c++

I've only recently got started with C++ and tried to build a simple class using different files (main, header and implementation). While doing that, I ran into a very strange (well, for me, at least) problem with #ifndef / #define. I'll show the code first:

```
// main.cpp :
#include <iostream>
#include "daytime.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DayTime sT = DayTime(75);
    cout << sT.getMin();

    return 0;
}

// daytime.h :
#ifndef DayTime
#define Daytime

class DayTime
{
    int min;

    public:
        DayTime(int min);
        int getMin();
        int getHour();
};

#endif

// daytime.cpp :
#include "daytime.h"

DayTime::DayTime(int min)
    : min(min) {}

DayTime::getMin()
{
    return this->min;
}

DayTime::getHour()
{
    return int (this->min / 60);
}
```

As you can see, there is a typo in `#define Daytime` in `daytime.h` - 'time' is written with a lowercase 't'. And here comes the strange part: as long as that typo is **there**, the program compiles and runs without problems. But the moment I correct it to `#define DayTime`, with uppercase 'T', it no longer complies and I get a multitude of errors:

```
2   0   main.cpp    In file included from main.cpp
9   11  daytime.h   [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'int'
9   11  daytime.h   [Error] expected ')' before 'int'
5   1   daytime.h   [Error] an anonymous struct cannot have function members
12  1   daytime.h   [Error] abstract declarator '<anonymous class>' used as declaration
D:\Dokumentumok\Prog\C++\Test\main.cpp  In function 'int main(int, char**)':
7   10  main.cpp    [Error] 'sT' was not declared in this scope
28      Makefile.win    recipe for target 'main.o' failed
```

I've been wasting hours on this by now, but I've always got back to this same issue: typo there, it works, typo gone, it doesn't - and I just don't get it. So I'd be very grateful for some assistance here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define DayTime` causes any future occurrences of `DayTime` to be replaced with the empty string.

So the name of your class in `class DayTime` (and its constructor) are getting deleted, causing issues: the compiler effectively sees:

```cpp
class
{
    int min;

    public:
        (int min);
        int getMin();
        int getHour();
};
```

---

Usually for this exact reason, when people make these include guards, they use something that is unlikely to show up as a real identifier. For example:

```cpp
#ifndef DAYTIME_H
#define DAYTIME_H

class DayTime {
  // blah blah blah
};

#endif
```

Comment: Indeed. Usually people would define all caps markers to keep track of includes, like this: `#define _DAYTIME_H`

Comment: `#pragma once` is a widely accepted alternative guard.

Comment: @AndyBrown I thought about suggesting `#pragma once`, but felt that it didn't illustrate the real point of my answer which is how `#define Foo` causes future uses of `Foo` to disappear. So I left it off in order to not be confusing.

Comment: @AndyBrown: Widely supported, but non-standard.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answers; both solutions worked fine (and I'll remember that #pragma is non-standard).

Comment: @Dan -- names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_DAYTIME_H`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code. This is **not** a standard convention for include guard names. You may well see it in the implementation of the standard library, which uses reserved identifiers in many places. Those identifiers are reserved so that the standard library doesn't step on user code and so that user code doesn't step on the standard library.